# Beginner python, "TypeError:'float' object is not callable"

Tags: python, for-loop

I have following problem, which I don't know how to code correctly:

You are given two lists, pressure and temperature, write a Python code to calculate the potential temperature. Print temperature, pressure, potential temperature with the same index line by line.

```
Temp=[59., 62., 67., 63., 68.]
Pressure=[970, 981, 984, 972, 992]
```

Note: Please use either 1000 or 1013 as P0 to calculate the potential temperature (define one variable P0). T needs to be in Kelvin.

I defined the formula for potential temperature as P0

```
Temp=[59., 62., 67., 63., 68.]
Pressure=[970., 981., 984., 972., 992.]
P0=[Temp[i](1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004]
for i in range (len(Temp)):
    print (Temp[i], Pressure[i], P0[i])
```

The error I'm recieving is ['float' object is not callable]

Comment: Can you share the calculation you're trying to perform (regardless of python)?

Comment: its because of your code that is not complete and messed up

Answer (score 1):

`Temp[i](1000/Pressure[i])` tries to call `Temp[i]` as though it is a function, trying to pass `1000 / Pressure[i]` as an argument - this raises the

> 'float' object is not callable

error message that you see.

You probably meant to multiply `Temp[i]` by `(1000/Pressure[i])`:

```
P0=[Temp[i] * (1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004]
```

Noting that `i` hasn't been defined at this stage, you may want to iterate through `Temp` or `Pressure`:

```
P0 = [t * (1000 / Pressure[i]) ** 287 / 1004 for i, t in enumerate(Temp)]
```

Or, iterating through the combination of the two lists in one go using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip):

```
P0 = [t * (1000 / p) ** 287 / 1004 for i, p in zip(Temp, Pressure)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of problems already in this line:

```
P0=[Temp[i](1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004]
```

what is i?

the error you're getting is because of:

```
 Temp[i](
```

are you trying to call Temp[i]? If you're multiplying, you should use an operator.

Perhaps you could go through some Python tutorial to get to get to know the syntax better.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things are messed up in your code:

This:

```
P0=[Temp[i](1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004]
```

is not a proper list comprehension.

Should be:

```
P0=[t*(1000/p)**(287)/1004 for t, p in zip(Temp,Pressure)]
```

And some minor spacing/syntax issues.

I'd rewrite your for loop including zip(). See the following:

```
Temp=[59., 62., 67., 63., 68.]
Pressure=[970., 981., 984., 972., 992.]
for temp, pressure in zip(Temp, Pressure):
    p0 = temp * (1000 / pressure) ** 287 / 1004
    print(temp, pressure, p0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line:

```
   P0 = [Temp[i](1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004]
```

When you write `Temp[i](1000/Pressure[i])`, you might expect it to be a multiplication operation, but it's actually a call. The interpreter considers the value at `Temp[i]` to be a [callable](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/23/python-internals-how-callables-work/). But, since the float object doesn't implement the `__call__` method (which is required to make anything to be callable), it leads to the error message you recieved ['float' object is not callable].

To correct this, you can re-write it as:

```
   P0 = [Temp[i] * (1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004]
```

Now, you'll be multiplying `Temp[i]` with the result of calculation from `(1000/Pressure[i])**(287)/1004`.